# Augmented Reality: Render Video on top of a marker

Tags: c++, 3d, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I'd like to render a video (can be any format as long as it works) on top of a marker, but I am not sure how to do this. I am using Artoolkit for desktop-based AR and QCAR for mobile AR. Eventually I want to get it done for both systems, therefore I am preferably looking for a video-library that I could use on both platforms.

Basically I know the steps that have to be done:

```
 - load video file
 - extract image according to current time
 - use image as texture 
 - apply marker's transformation matrix to textured rectangle
```

Which libraries could I use to achieve the first two steps?

Comment: Hello @Pedro do you know how to update kpmHandle with new and existing reference set to avoid long loading time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which libraries could I use to achieve the first two steps?

Take a look into the libavcodec library (you can start [here](http://ffmpeg.org/)), but take into account that it is quite complex.

Comment: I was hoping a library, that provides a simple way to access frames from videos exists. Something like  >>Image* i = getImageFromVideo(time) . Alternatively I am looking for an open source project, that has implemented this already and where I could extract the code from.

Comment: @Pedro I hoped as well that I would find something like that, but I don't think such thing exists. You can find example for libavcodec if that helps.

Comment: I don't want to spend a lot of time with that, it's actually not that important, so I guess I'll leave it. It just would have made a nice demo.

Comment: I think you can use normal push navigation and play video with AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer background. It'll be the best alternative !!!!